# Expected behavior while printing reference and dereference of a variable

Tags: rust

I am new to rust and have this fundamental doubt:

```
let x = String::from("hello world");
let y = &x;
println!("y: {}", y);
println!("value of x is: {}", *y);
```

I understand that `y` is a reference to the value hello world stored in heap. But why do `y` print the value of `x` and not the memory location of `y`. If this is the expected behavior, why do we need to deference and access the value of a variable using `*` because `&x` already gives the value of the variable?

Comment: In short: because Rust, for your convenience, has blanket implementations of the formatting traits for references that forward them to the referent. And this is a duplicate. Let me find it...

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I understand what you are saying! The println macro is automatically dereferencing the value when I print &x. But I then used the debugger to see what is the value of y. There I see both x and y have value "hello world". Shouldn't the value of y be a memory location?

Comment: The debugger is probably _also_ dereferencing it for your convenience.